# Have to click twice to execute onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I have problem where I have to click twice to swap button text and class on the first time I click it. All the other times it changes on first click. 
I already tried removing click inside changeUnits() function but in this case I can change to Celcius once and cannot swap values anymore. I'm assigning value and class because I'm going to use it later in another api call to retrieve weather in specified units.
Does anyone see what am I doing wrong?

html

```
<button id="units" class="Fahrenheit" onclick="changeUnits();callWeather()">F</button>
```

javascript

```
     function changeUnits() {
       if($("#units").hasClass("Fahrenheit")) {

           $(".Fahrenheit").click(function() {
                $(".Fahrenheit").text("C");
                $(this).removeClass('Fahrenheit').addClass('Celcius');
            });
        }
         else if($("#units").hasClass("Celcius")) {
            $(".Celcius").click(function() {
                $(".Celcius").text("F");
                $(this).removeClass('Celcius').addClass('Fahrenheit');
            });
         }          
        }
```

Comment: you're executing your `changeUnits()` on first click and in that function you're setting up another click listener - that's why you have to click twice. Remove the unnecessary listeners (`$(".Fahrenheit").click(function() {` and `$(".Celcius").click(function() {`)  and it will work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this .. No need to check for class you only need `toggleClass()` and just check for `.text()` to change the text to C or F

```
function changeUnits(el) {          // pass el here
   var ThisText = $(el).text(),     // get text from this element
       fah_or_ce = $(el).text().trim() == 'C' ? 'F' : 'C';  // set fah_or_ce as a variable and check if C return F and if else return C
   $(el).text(fah_or_ce );       // change text with new text
   $(el).toggleClass('Fahrenheit Celcius');  // toggle between classes
}
```

and use it `onclick = "changeUnits(this)"`

**Demo 1**

```js
function changeUnits(el) {
   var ThisText = $(el).text(),
       fah_or_ce = $(el).text().trim() == 'C' ? 'F' : 'C';
   $(el).text(fah_or_ce );    
   $(el).toggleClass('Fahrenheit Celcius');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="units" class="Fahrenheit" onclick="changeUnits(this)">F</button>
```

And for me I prefer to use `.on(click)` event instead of inline `onclick`

**Demo 2**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#units').on('click' , function(){
        changeUnits(this);
        // you can use callWeather() as well
        //callWeather();
    });
});

function changeUnits(el) {
   var ThisText = $(el).text(),
       fah_or_ce = $(el).text().trim() == 'C' ? 'F' : 'C';
   $(el).text(fah_or_ce );    
   $(el).toggleClass('Fahrenheit Celcius');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="units" class="Fahrenheit">F</button>
```

Comment: @KarynaMaklakova You're welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what why you use the function changeUnits only when button is click. For me it should be more when `$("#units")` change class. But it will be better to use this code for you :

```
<button id="units" class="Fahrenheit" onclick="changeUnits();callWeather()">F</button>
<button id="units" class="Celsius" onclick="changeUnits();callWeather()" style="display: none;">C</button>



function changeUnits() {
    if($("#units").hasClass("Fahrenheit")) {
        $(".Fahrenheit").hide();
        $(".Celcius").show();
    }else if($("#units").hasClass("Celcius")) {
        $(".Fahrenheit").show();
        $(".Celcius").hide();
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

**Explanation:**

Your problem is quite simple, the fact that you have to press twice is due to the fact that your function that really does the swap is affected once you click,
 a simple idea is to assign your function when the document loads

**Working code, that is really similar to yours:**

```js
function initialize()
        {
            if($("#units").hasClass("Fahrenheit")) 
            {

                $(".Fahrenheit").click(function() 
                {
                    $(".Fahrenheit").text("C");
                    $(this).removeClass("Fahrenheit").addClass("Celcius");
                    $(this).click(initialize());
                });
            }
            else if($("#units").hasClass("Celcius"))
            {
                $(".Celcius").click(function() 
                {
                    $(".Celcius").text("F");
                    $(this).removeClass("Celcius").addClass("Fahrenheit");
                    $(this).click(initialize());
                });
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<button id="units" class="Fahrenheit">F</button>
</body>
</html>
```